# how to generate google oauth for a site with multiple games

Tags: google-oauth

I am creating an arcade website with multiple games. should I generate a single oauth client id for the entire domain or should I generate a unique oauth id for each individual game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more interesting question is: What user experience would you like to give users?

If you want to build your brand across each of the games, you'll configure a single project (ZBestArcadeGames.com, for instance) in Cloud console. Users will be prompted to authorize your entire site. Whether you create one client or multiple clients in this case is not super-important, since you can configure multiple redirect_uris for a single client. Users will consent once to sign-in to your site and they can authenticate to every game w/o additional consent prompts. Similarly, if they revoke access to your site, they will no longer be able to authenticate to any game in the site. This may be the typical choice if your company develops all games it hosts.

If, on the other hand, you want to highlight the individuality of each game and allow users to consent / de-authorize authenticating to them individually you need to create separate projects each with its own brand (and in this case you will need to configure at least one client in each project). This may be the typical choice if each of the games is developed by a company and there's no implied trust between the games you host and your company, and you'd not like to sign terms-of-service on behalf of these other companies--you might even want to ask the developers of each original game to register separately (using the redirect_uri for your site).

Comment: That makes sense. I just noticed that I can only link up to 20 apps. Since I plan to have much more than 20 games I think I will have to generate a client for each one.